# flutter web app showing blank screen after releasing on Node JS server

Tags: node.js, flutter, flutter-web

I have made a Flutter Web app and it is running perfectly on Debug and Release mode. But when I deploy it to my NodeJS webserver which serves the Webpage index.html from the contents which were built by running command `flutter build web`, I get a blank screen (White) whenever I try to access the webpage using google chrome by typing out the URL. I have inspected the webpage too but found no errors on it.
Can anyone find any reasons for this and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: does it have the same output with localhost debugging?